# Error with safeTransferFrom erc721

Tags: erc-721

I have created a contract of a marketplace in a modularised way, that is, I define a contract for the marketplace itself and another one for the auction.

In the main contract I extend ERC721BurnableUpgradeable and in the Auction contract I extend ERC721HolderUpgradeable.

To the ERC721HolderUpgradeable contract I pass in its migration the address of the main contract (which has an IERC721Upgradeable interface).

Everything went smoothly, mint, auction creation, 1-2-x placeBid...
Now when I want to make the claim from the admin account I have this error that I don't understand why I get when I execute the safeTransferFrom method...

```
tokenContract.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _auction_bidder[tokenContract][tokenId], tokenId);

reason: 'ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved'...
```

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Hi Damian, could you please drop in the code you are actually calling? And also, please list the command you send to get this error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are not adding an approval for the transfer.

There are two ways to transfer tokens:

1. Direct transfer with `transfer` function. You own the tokens and you send them to an arbitrary recipient
2. An indirect transfer. You give address X allowance (`approve` function) to withdraw some amount of your tokens. Typically, in a second transaction, you tell the other contract (X) to do whatever it needed the tokens for - for example a trade. So X then withdraws the tokens from you (with `transferFrom`) using the allowance you gave it earlier.

Comment: You are so good! You are so right!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have seen things related to what you say, about authorising an account. But I am making the claim with the admin account, with which I created the contract. I should not authorise the admin of the contract?
I think I'm failing in something else....
I leave the code of my contract for you to see.

https://pastebin.com/EkjWZWYY